# How to pass and retrieve table row data using QueryString in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I have a DataTable

I have created this

```
var a=[];
$("#DataTable tbody").on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{       
    a=table.row( this ).data();
});
```

Now I want to pass this array a[] to another web form using query string on button click

```
<asp:Button ID="button" onclick="click_function"/>
```

And then

```
[WebMethod]
click_function()
          {
          var darr = [];
          darr = table.row('.selected').data();

          var url = "QuestionDetail.htm?QuestionId=" + darr;
          window.location.href = url;
          }
```

How should I?

And also I have to retrieve this array in that new webform. So, that I will get data of that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that

```
// JavaScript    
var table = $("#DataTable").DataTable();
```

If that's the case then I would add a hidden field on the form

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hfSelectedRow" />
```

and set the data to that field

```
// JavaScript
$("#DataTable tbody").on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{       
    $('#hfSelectedRow').val(table.row( this ).data());
});
```

so now on the server you can retreive the data by

```
[WebMethod]
protected void button_click() 
{
    Response.Redirect("QuestionDetail.htm?QuestionId=" + hfSelectedRow.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Employeedetail : System.Web.UI.Page {
    // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string strEid = Request.QueryString["EId"];
        DisplayEmployeeDetail(strEid);
    }

    public DataTable DisplayEmployeeDetail(string strEid) {           
        DAL.EMPDA db = new DAL.EMPDA();
        EMPBOL objEMPBOL = new EMPBOL();
        objEMPBOL.e_id = strEid;
        DataTable dt = db.EmpDetail(objEMPBOL);

        Txtcode.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_Code"].ToString();
        TxtFName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_firstname"].ToString();
        TxtLName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_lastname"].ToString();
        TxtDesig.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_designation"].ToString();
        Txtbirthdate.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_dob"].ToString();
        TxtQualification.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_qualification"].ToString();
        Txtempcity.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_city"].ToString();
        Txtemailid.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_email"].ToString();
        Txtphonenumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_phone"].ToString();
        Txtsalry.Text = dt.Rows[0]["emp_salary"].ToString();
        return dt;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a Java expert, but I'm guessing that this post would be better if you'd include a bit of comments and explanations